# Change the position of an element in jwplayer?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, jwplayer, video-player

I'm using jwplayer 6. Is there any way to make the **eclapsedBackground** (01:19) element close to **durationBackground** (2:10) element? So that in the end, we would have 01:19 / 2:10 (just like YouTube) instead of having them separate.

[image: jwplayer]

This is how they are formatted in the xml file.

```
<element name="elapsedBackground" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAeCAYAAAAPSW++AAAAFklEQVR42mP8//8/AzbAOCoxKjHcJAA3uVnFd64sVwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>

<element name="durationBackground" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAeCAYAAAAPSW++AAAAFklEQVR42mP8//8/AzbAOCoxKjHcJAA3uVnFd64sVwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>
```

Comment: It is not possible to re-arrange the elements, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done easily. There is no easy solution.